# Guice Multibinder Doesn't Work with Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework, dependency-injection, guice

Using Play 2.5.8 with Scala 2.11.8.

I've a trait `RequestMatcher` and multiple implementations of it. I'd like to have a `Seq[RequestMatcher]` injected in my service. My module looks like the following:

```
class FeignModule(environment: Environment, configuration: Configuration) extends AbstractModule with AkkaGuiceSupport {
  def configure() = {
    val requestMatcherBinder = Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder(), classOf[RequestMatcher])
    // TODO: Allow for user specified matchers
    requestMatcherBinder.addBinding().to(classOf[DefaultPathMatcher])
    requestMatcherBinder.addBinding().to(classOf[DefaultMethodMatcher])
    requestMatcherBinder.addBinding().to(classOf[DefaultQueriesMatcher])
    requestMatcherBinder.addBinding().to(classOf[DefaultHeadersMatcher])
    requestMatcherBinder.addBinding().to(classOf[DefaultBodyMatcher])

    // TODO: Allow for user specified actors
    bindActor[DefaultRecordingService]("recordingService")
  }
}
```

The injection target is as follows:

```
@javax.inject.Singleton
class FeignService @Inject()(@Named("recordingService") val recordingService: ActorRef,
                             val feignProperties: FeignProperties,
                             val matchers: Seq[RequestMatcher])
                            (implicit val ec: ExecutionContext) {
}
```

But

> play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[ProvisionException:
>   Unable to provision, see the following errors:
>
> 1) No implementation for
>   scala.collection.Seq was
>   bound.   while locating
>   scala.collection.Seq
>       for the 3rd parameter of service.FeignService.(FeignService.scala:19)

I know the module is read by Play because the Actor (1st parameter to `FeignService`) is injected just fine. I have the `guice-multibindings` jar on classpath too.

What's wrong?

Comment: Multibindings's SetBinder is only good for injecting a Set, not an ordered Java `List` or a Scala `Seq`. You can use a `@Provides` method to handle Seq injection requests using the Set, but the ordering will be undefined unless you define/implement one.

Comment: @JeffBowman "_Multibindings's SetBinder is only good for injecting a Set_" I don't think that's true. According to their [doc](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/multibindings/Multibinder.html), "_If desired, Collection<Provider<Snack>> can also be injected._". Besides, I tried with `Set` too, no cigar.

Comment: Yes, in the sense of `Set<Provider<T>>` or `Map<K, Provider<T>>` for Multibinder and MapBinder respectively, and a `Collection<T>` and `Collection<Provider<T>>` aliased to the Sets, but not arbitrary Collection subtypes and certainly not Scala Seq or Set. Make sure we're talking about a java.util.Set here.

Comment: I am having the same issue, were you able to find a solution?

Comment: @codeCruncher no, I’d to create a container class

Answer (score 2):

Thread is a little old but if anybody (like me) has the same problem: The correct answer is in comments to this question but was probably overlooked: guice Multibinder injects Java collections, not scala collections

Comment: I love you. You can inject java.util.Set and then convert back to scala collection using scala.collection.JavaConverters._